# How costly is unpersist operation on spark RDDs?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I was wondering, how costly can be`rdd.unpersist()` operation on spark RDDs ?, and does **Storage Level** setting impact performance of this operation ? Any benchmark(results/technique) will be very help full.

Comment: I wonder why you ask. I cannot imagine a reason to worry about `unpersist` performance! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unpersist` releases the RDD from cache (memory and disk) and deletes the shuffle files it depends on. For this it needs to send a message to the executors. It should be the cheapest operation you can do with an RDD — probably not worth benchmarking.

Note also that when an RDD is garbage collected, `unpersist` is automatically called on it. So you cannot avoid this cost anyway.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense.